# www+https redirection does not work even though redirection has been added in .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I'm currently doing www+https redirection where I hope that my website able to redirect from http://example.com to https://www.example.com but it does not work even I have added redirection in .htaccess file.
Below is my redirection which I have added in .htaccess file and supposedly able to work since I search everywhere this is the most common redirection that I can found:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Even though I have added this line, and try to type http://example.com, it somehow still does not redirect to https://www.example.com and I have run out of idea. I also did try to add a redirection in httpd-vhosts.conf and disable it from reading .htaccess file does not work as well.
Below is my configuration in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/example"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/example/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Below are logs that I manage to  get:

```
    RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com' [NC] => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='/index.php/news-and-events/news-and-events/news' pattern='(/|\\.htm|\\.php|\\.html|/[^.]*)$' [NC] => matched
    RewriteCond: input='D:/wamp64/www/example/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\\%3D)' => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='base64_encode.*\\(.*\\)' => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='(\\<|%3C).*script.*(\\>|%3E)' [NC] => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='GLOBALS(=|\\[|\\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})' => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='_REQUEST(=|\\[|\\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})' => not-matched
    pass through D:/wamp64/www/example/index.php
init rewrite engine with requested URL /, referer: http://intranet/
```

Below was my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.htm|\.php|\.html|/[^.]*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

Below are my httpd-ssl.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>

    #   General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/example"
    ServerName localhost:443

    ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   Server Certificate:
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/key/example.crt"
    #SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-dsa.crt"
    #SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-ecc.crt"

    #   Server Private Key:

    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/key/example.key"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

<Directory "d:/wamp4/www/example">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Require all denied
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Below is my hosts.file:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com
::1 example.com www.example.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

Can anyone give me any idea or help me or point me out if I've done anything wrong on this. BTW, I have my certificate point at httpd-ssl.comf file. Please do let me know if you need any more info and TIA!

Comment: How are you testing ? Refreshing page in browser ? Browser cache could be playing tricks so I would always use `Curl` from the command line for testing eg: `curl --head -L http://example.com`. Otherwise I would look in the Apache log files. There may be a misconfiguration in your files.

Comment: Hi, I do try by refresh page and clear all history and everything retry again, still does not work. How to use curl --head -L http://example.com? First time to hear this new thing. I did go through my logs, previously it shows You configured HTTP(80) on standard https(443) port! but I manage to fix that and it does not show any error now unless I need to change my log to another configuration in order to get more details.

Comment: BTW, few files have been added for your reference.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think these logs help. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/6843158) to enable the rewrite log (depends on your Apache version, from version 2.4 the directives are different). Then the best would be to extract only the relevant lines from the log immediately after testing your site. Feel free to update your question with results.

Comment: Actually, those logs were what I get after I put LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6 in httpd-conf file. And I'm sorry but what did you mean by extract only relevant after testing? I need to test my redirection with http://example.com in any browser then there will be logs appear after?

Comment: From the log you posted it looks like the "debug" logs are already enabled. However, that would seem to be the logs for other directives that you've not referenced in the question? However, if the redirect you've stated in the question is not working then there would seem to be something more fundamental at fault here. What happens exactly? From the server config you've posted, `www.example.com` wouldn't even be accessible? Is this handled by a different vHost container? You don't even need mod_rewrite for this - assuming you are using the server config  (and not `.htaccess`) for this?

Comment: Actually https://www.example.com is work and I just want to have the website to redirect from http://example.com to https://www.example.com. I tried to get more info from logs so it would help me to troubleshoot/find where the issue or root cause at. If that log is for other directives, I have to check again where the issue at T_T

Comment: Hi all, new logs have been added, please help to review if this is correct. I hope this is correct because I found this logs within another directive.

Comment: The logs you posted don't appear to cover the relevant redirect directives? However, those log entries already appear to be for `https://www.example.com/` (as stated by the `referer`)?! If `www.example.com` does work then where is this configured in your server config? Where is SSL configured? As mentioned above, the vHost you posted above only accepts requests to HTTP + `example.com` (not `www`)???

Comment: Sorry that one line was missing out from httpd-vhosts.conf, the line added. My SSL was actually configured in https-ssl.conf where I point my certificate at httpd-ssl.conf file. I don't think I need to change my configuration to 443 right since I have point my certificate in httpd-ssl.conf file. I'm sorry if my question kind of stupid but I have been struggling for some time to do this. None of my colleague and me familiar with apache and I needs to put more effort to work on this. :(((

Comment: Hello?? Anyone can help me with this??

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it has a better formed question in https://serverfault.com/q/1011208/274176 and it has an upvoted & working solution there.